# Haskell type coercion for strings

Tags: haskell

On this code I'm able to construct a list of `Algo`s using some direct constructors like `Lit` and `Nom`, but also from integers. This happens because `Algo` derives `Num`.

Is it possible to do something similar for strings?

```
type Nr = Double
data Algo
  = Nom Nr
  | Lit String
  | Und 
  deriving (Show)

instance Num Algo where
  (+) (Nom a) (Nom b)=Nom(a+b)
  (+) _ _=Und
  (*) (Nom a) (Nom b)=Nom(a*b)
  (*) _ _=Und
  abs (Nom a)=Nom(abs a)
  abs _=Und
  signum (Nom a)=Nom(signum a)
  signum _=Und
  fromInteger a=Nom(fromInteger a)

main=do
  print ([1,2,3,Und,Nom 5,Lit "x"]::[Algo])
```

running ok with result:

```
[Nom 1.0,Nom 2.0,Nom 3.0,Und,Nom 5.0,Lit "x"]
```

desired code:

```
print (["test",1,2,3,Und,Nom 5,Lit "x"]::[Algo])
```

will give an error of course...
where does the conversion occurs? at parse/compile?

readPrec didn't help either

Comment: What do you expect `"test"` to be "converted" to exactly?

Comment: to Lit "test" automatic as with the numbers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `"test"` to be automatically "converted" to `Algo`, you would need to define an instance of [`IsString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString) and then use the GHC extension [`OverloadedStrings`](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-17-overloaded-strings.html):

```
instance IsString Algo where
  fromString = Lit
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f49cee58b36265ed)</kbd>

So that the following works correctly:

```
print ["test", 1, 2, 3, Und, Nom 5, Lit "x"]
-- [Lit "test",Nom 1.0,Nom 2.0,Nom 3.0,Und,Nom 5.0,Lit "x"]
```